# Can i get help to identify 8 numeric digits in free form text column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can i get help to identify 8 numeric digits in free form text column

Example - data in the column is like this

```
[record 1] i love my country 12345678 ^ 2343-000
[record 2] hey bro  what are you doing 123456 ^ 23
[record 3] dear friends  1234-5678 ^ 23400
```

Result should be- i want to see only - [Record 1] & [Record 3]

Note ^ is the delimiter . I am trying this using the dataframe . Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexp_extract` function to extract number and then use filter to filter required data.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------+
|data                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|[record 1] i love my country 12345678 ^ 2343-000  |
|[record 2] hey bro  what are you doing 123456 ^ 23|
|[record 3] dear friends  1234-5678 ^ 23400        |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

```
scala> df
.withColumn("extracted_digits",regexp_extract($"data","[0-9-]{8}+",0))
.filter(trim($"extracted_digits") =!= "" && $"extracted_digits".isNotNull )
.show(false)
+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|data                                            |extracted_digits|
+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|[record 1] i love my country 12345678 ^ 2343-000|12345678        |
|[record 3] dear friends  1234-5678 ^ 23400      |1234-567        |
+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```